# Derivation of Proca mass equation with chern-simons term

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, chern-simons-theory

In a paper named [Self-dual factorization of the Proca equation with Chern-Simons term in 4K − 1 dimensions](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(86)91541-8), the lagrangian density 
$$ \mathcal{L}= -\frac{1}{4} F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}+\frac{1}{4}\mu\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha}F_{\mu\nu} A_{\alpha}+\frac{1}{2}m^2 A^{\alpha}A_{\alpha}$$
give equation of motion.
$$\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu}+m^2 A^{\nu}+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{\nu\alpha\beta}F_{\alpha\beta}=0$$ I am able to derive some results but could not derive following result even after many attempts. It says to multiply above equation of motion with $\epsilon_{\nu\delta\eta}$ and using $\partial_\mu A^{\mu}=0$ and again using equation of motion we get following equation.
$$(\partial_\mu \partial^\mu+m^2+\mu^2 ) ^\ast F^{\nu} +\mu m^2A^{\nu}=0 $$
where dual field tensor is defined as
$$^\ast F^{\nu}=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{\nu\alpha\beta}F_{\alpha\beta}. $$
Somebody help me in deriving this relation.